# Why `.before` for custom jQuery object doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I tried jQuery codes like this:

```
var a=$("<a>1</a>")
a=a.before("<b></b>")
a[0].outerHTML
```

And the result is still `<a>1</a>`, which I expected to get `<b></b><a>1</a>`.. It seems that `.before` doesn't work at all..

===

I understand that `a.before` will work well if `a` is part of the DOM . But what if `a` is not inserted into the DOM and I need to insert something before `a`(not wrap `a`)? That's why I used `a=a.before("<b></b>")`. Does anyone have ideas about how to change a jQuery object in-place before it is inserted into the DOM?

Comment: Does console show you anything?

Comment: Please show the actual code. `outerhtml` would just throw an error.

Comment: Next time, show us your code (JSFiddle can help you) if you want to get the answer

Comment: the actual code is `a[0].outerHTML..

Comment: @Firegun maybe it would help if you would explain *why* you think that `.outerHTML` should include the `<b>`.

Comment: @Pointy I was just wondering where the `<b>` goes to..

Comment: @Firegun well, you haven't put the `<a>` into the DOM yet, so the `<b>` really has nowhere to go; the `<a>` has no parent element. Even if you did add it before the `<a>`, `.outerHTML` would not show it to you because that's not what it does.

Comment: @Firegun the `<b>` is before the `<a>` just like you expect.. see here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Aqzu/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `a.before` returns the original set, which only contains `a` and whatever you insert *inside* it, but not before (or after, or around) it. Try using a dummy container, change the `before` by `prepend` and read `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML`:

```
var a = $("<a>1</a>");
var x = $('<dummy/>').append(a);
x.prepend("<b></b>"); 
console.log(x[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try the same codes to an existing HTML element in place of "var a=$("1")". I think that should work perfectly!

Comment: **HTML** <div id="test">World!</div>
var a=$("#test")
a=a.before("<b>Hello</b>")
a[0].outerHTML

Try something like above! It should work.

Comment: Hmm! Please see below pattern if it helps you to solve your problem.
`var html = "<div id='check'><div id='test'>a</div></div>";
html = $( html );
html.find( "#test" ).before( "<b>Deepak</b>" );
console.log( html);`